# Symmetric function of the roots is a rational function of the coefficients.

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

I'm reading through Stewart's Galois Theory. In chapter one, the author asserts that for a cubic polynomial with roots $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2$, and $\omega$ a principal cube root of unity, consider

$u=(\alpha_0+ \omega \alpha_1 + \omega^2 \alpha_2)^3$

$v=(\alpha_0+ \omega \alpha_2 + \omega^2 \alpha_1)^3$

It can be shown that $u+v$ is a symmetric function of the roots, that is, the value is invariant under any permutation of the roots. Then the author asserts that the function can then be written as a rational function of the coefficients. In this particular example, I can work out the details and see why it works. But in general why is this assertion true for polynomials of any degree (or other symmetric functions) ?

Comment: Short answer: because every permutation in $S_n$ is generated by a trasposition and a $n$-cycle

Comment: The [Fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials). And [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) are also useful.